# How to Troubleshoot Dexie bound on IDBKeyRange Error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, dexie

I'm using [Dexie.js](https://dexie.org/) version `3.0.3-rc.3` in a Vue JS project and I occasionally run into this exception in Chrome (86):

> Failed to execute 'bound' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key.↵ DataError: Failed to execute 'bound' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key.

Here's a screenshot of the full error:

[image]

I'm fairly certain the problem lies with something in my data being `undefined`, but I'm trying to find a good way to troubleshoot this. I paused the Chrome dev tools on exceptions and inspected the code around this particular part of Dexie, but it doesn't reveal what data was used to make this exception occur.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find out what's actually wrong? It feels a bit like a needle in a haystack.

**== Update ==**

Below is the full call stack:

[image]

Comment: Try `monitor(IDBKeyRange.bound)` in devtools console before running your code.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with `monitor()`. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the call stack. I know it can be long until you reach a frame within your application code, but the failing call should be there!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question with the call stack as you suggested. There aren't any references to my app, so is this potentially a bug in Dexie?

Comment: Let me know if you want me to move this to a GitHub issue on the Dexie respository.  It looks like an undefined value is getting passed into `makeIDKeyRange()`: https://d.pr/i/63ABsX

Comment: I finally figured it out! I was passing an `undefined` value into a compound `where` clause. I created an issue here in case you want to handle the exception in Dexie: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/1158

Comment: By the way, Dexie is seriously amazing. You've done excellent work here! 

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You seem to be right about that your call stack did not show your app code frame - which makes it hard to debug! I'm looking at your github issue now and understand the situation that could be improved if dexie would fail faster when passing undefined values to whereclause operators in general.